# サービス自動起動時の起動ユーザ設定方法

Tags: linux, amazon-linux, systemd

python で作ったプログラムをクラウドでサービスと動かそうと思っています
Amazon の EC2 というサーバーが有名みたいなので無料枠で借りてみました

そこでサーバー起動時に自動起動するようにしたいです

/etc/stytemd/system/test.service
にサービスファイルを置いたところ自動起動はできたのですが
rootユーザで動かすのは過剰権限なので
ユーザ(デフォルトのec2-user)権限で動かしたいです

ユニットファイルにはユーザを指定するようなオプションはないみたいで
起動コマンドに sudo とかつけるしかないでしょうか？

/etc/stytemd/user/ の中において
`systemctl --user status`
のようなことができるって記事もあったのですが
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
というエラーになります

OS は amazon linux2 という一番新しいもので
インスタンスタイプは t2 micro というタイプです

よろしくお願いします

Comment: 参考までに、Amazon Linux2 ではなくて Ubuntu の systemd ですが、man の `systemd.exec(5)` に `CREDENTIALS` という項目があって、`User=`, `Group=` で指定できる様です。

Comment: ユーザ起動はできました。ありがとうございます